# Debugging multiple hadoop jvms with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, multiprocessing

I have a problem that appears in pseudo-distributed mode, but not in standalone mode, and I'm hoping to scratch up some ideas on how to debug this.

Some of my mapper tasks are returning code 143. I'd love to drop a breakpoint on System.exit() and see who's calling this why, but I have to get the debugger running on that mapper.

I can get the task tracker up in the debugger by modifying my bin/hadoop script and remotely connecting to localhost:5000:

```
...
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "tasktracker" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker
  HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS $HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS"
# TBMark!
  HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

...and I can get the first mapper (or by a minor tweak, reducer) into Eclipse by adding this into my conf/mapred-site.xml and remotely connecting to localhost:5001:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5001,server=y,suspend=y</value>
</property>
```

My problem is that the failure happens at random and not on the first mapper.

Unsatisfactory ideas that come to mind include:

1. Somehow replace System.exit() with my own method that does a stack trace. (How does one hook a system call?)
2. Just keep trying to debug the mappers one by one and run each one to completion before debugging the next. (It *might* work...)
3. Track down every last place in hadoop that calls System.exit() and write a distinct signature to a log. (*Yuck*)
4. Make the debugger port number variable such that, if I can guess which one is going to fail and the delay doesn't make the bug go away, I can attach to that jvm and debug it. (Many if's, and I don't know any way to make this variable in the .xml file.)
5. If failure can be predicted to happen on a certain attempt, break the task tracker just before the jvm launch and hand edit the script file. (Desperate times call for desperate measures)

Any suggestions or ideas for how to make my bad ideas above work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-run a failed map task with the [IsolationRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/mapred_tutorial.html#IsolationRunner)

In case it fails again you should be able to add the debug options!